# Printing RAW jobs from AIX 5.3 to Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, aix

We're trying to move a program from a legacy Windows 2003 print server over to a Windows 2008 R2 one.

The program takes output sent from an AIX server and then processes it. It gets the data by way of a remote print queue on the AIX box.

Now for some reason, when we send the job to the 2003 box, the job comes through as RAW, as it should. When we send it to the 2008 one with exactly the same settings in AIX it spools as TEXT. The program we use expects RAW output and ignores anything else.

We've run through everything we can think of - the Print Processor is set to a RAW datatype, the AIX box is definitely sending it as RAW.. but all jobs come through as TEXT and are ignored.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Problem resolved by following the steps outlined here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150930

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.